# Self-test monitor behavior: VGA vs HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

I switched connection on my DELL monitor from `VGA` to `HDMI` and (obviously) the setting on a monitor itself.  Everything works fine.

The only thing that bothers me a little bit that in VGA mode the monitor was blanking itself after I shut-down my laptop.  With `HDMI` connection it runs a self-test continuously (ignoring the shutdown).

Does `HDMI` interface allows for a monitor to detect whether it's plugged-in or not?

Are there any settings on either side that I can change to impact this behavior?

If it matters, my laptop runs Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the HDMI interface supports detection, however, not all monitor brands and/or driver versions support it.

For example, I have a computer connected to two monitors, and one is an older Sharp monitor that does not blank out when connected with HDMI, but it does blank out when using VGA or DVI. My other Asus monitor does blank out with HDMI, so I use the HDMI cable for the Asus and the DVI cable for the Sharp. This way both monitors blank when I turn off my computer.

As for if there is anything you can do about it, it probably has nothing to do with your computer, it's more likely to be the monitor software. See if you can upgrade that, otherwise try a different connector type.